# Claim rental expenses as a tax credit

Tags: taxes, canada, ontario, renter

If I am renting the apartment I live in, can I claim part of the rent I pay as a tax credit?
I am looking at this [can-you-claim-rent-in-ontario](http://blog.turbotax.ca/can-you-claim-rent-in-ontario/)

But it does not mention if you need to be below a certain income category to claim this credit? I see no difference to my refund whether I claim this amount or not?

Comment: Are you living in your own rental property or are you renting someone elses rental property? Usually in most countries you wouldn't be able to claim rent you pay unless it is for business purposes.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'own rental property'? The unit is owned by someone, I pay that person rent every month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property tax credit has been rolled into the Ontario Trillium Benefit.  You can calculate how much you will receive here.

http://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/taxcredits/CalculatorQuestions.asp

For example a single person paying $500 / mo rent and earning $20,000 will get $396 for a property tax credit.

This will be paid monthly and won't change the amounts on your tax return.  You just need to fill out the ON-BEN form.  http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/5006-tg/